# Is there a snap to point functionality built into the asp.net web forms charts?

Tags: forms, web, charts, point

I'm using a chart control to display a line chart with some data inside an asp.net web forms web page and what I would like to achieve is: as I move the mouse over the chart I would like the cursor of the mouse to automatically jump or snap to the datapoint closest to the mouse cursor OR, as an alternative, as I move the mouse, have a crosshair automatically snap to the nearest point and possibly display the x and y values / coordinates of the crosshair.

I've tried searching all over the place and the most relevant links I found were of someone making a custom tooltip for the chart. Can this be achieved with the asp.net web forms chart control?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I - the user - am moving my mouse towards the chart and all of a sudden it snaps to a place on the screen that I didn't move it to?  Is that what you are suggesting?  If so I would rethink what you are trying to do and why you are trying to do it because in book that is a terrible user experience.

Comment: That's why I mentioned a crosshair that snaps to "a place on the screen [you] didn't" move the mouse to. The mouse cursor would stay put. And it's not just any point on the screen, it's a data point on the chart. This is so I don't have to fiddle around with my mouse until I get the cursor close enough to trigger a tooltip, especially when there are many points so close to one another that I can easily trigger a tooltip for a point I didn't want to. How is that a bad user experience?